# Does Webform CiviCRM event registration respect the "Registration End Date" setting?

Tags: civievent, drupal, webform-civicrm, registration

CiviCRM events can have a "Registration End Date" (and start date, for that matter):

[image: Start/end date]

Is the following setting on CiviCRM Webform (under CiviCRM > Event Registration > Registration Options) meant to take this Registration Start/End Date into account, or is it only checking the Event End Date?

[image: Registration options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Those checkboxes apply to the event end date, not the registration end date.